# Partner Community User - not enabled for activities?

Tags: partner-communities, global-actions

I have activated a test Partner Community user and granted that user access to Accounts, Contacts, Cases, etc.  I have also created a tab in the Community that allows the user to log a visit using the standard LogAVisit global action.  When I add the action and save. and then log in to the community as a test user in incognito mode - then the tab containing the 'Log a Visit' global action is not visible.  Are Partner Community users unable to use activities?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with the help of SF support. The solution is to drag the "Create Record button" into the layout and then select the correct type of action, in my instance the "Log a Visit" action. This works fine.